# How to do print console in excel custom function

Tags: excel, office-js, office-addins, excel-addins, excel-web-addins

How can I print console any thing in excel custom function. I have tried many things but it not displaying anything in the console.
Any documentation available then please, suggest it. or share the link for that.
I have tried this code.

```
    /**
     * Multiply By 10.
     * @customfunction
     * @helpurl https://sfjlemon.ifour-consultancy.net/taskpane.html
     * @param count First number.
     * @returns {number} The multiply by ten.
     */
    async function count(count) {
cosole.log("count value",count)
      return count * 10;
    }
```

Comment: What code have you tried so far? Where are you looking for the results?

Comment: I haved added the code in the above question

Comment: Where do you expect the output to be displayed?

Answer (score 0):

A separate console window is not displayed when you use the `console` class in Office web add-ins. Instead, if you debugging the add-in you could find such output in the debug console window of VSCode (see https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging) or web browser itself if you run the solution in the browser.